# HTML Table combining colspan and rowspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to make a html table with the following layout:

```
+-------+---+
|       |   |
+-------+   +
|       |   |
+-----+-----+
|     |     |
+-----+-----+
```

I am using a `colgroup` to divide the entire table into 5% pieces,
and then applying `colspan` and `rowspan` to combine some pieces together. So far, I've had no success. I am wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. A table is needed to accommodate email styling possibilities.

EDIT: https://plnkr.co/edit/CHmiOuKpUlPsVJanLl7l?p=preview
Code as requested

Comment: Post your code here, not on some 3rd webpage.

Comment: And why is that so important?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do but looks like your HTML is invalid. `<col>` is a self-closing HTML tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your exact colspan and rowspan you would have to do something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the code in action:

https://jsfiddle.net/npjkrb55/1/

Comment: Kijk, daar hebben we wat aan. Bedankt voor je tijd! (Look, there have we what on. Thanks for your time!)

Comment: Glad I could help :)